# Remove shortcut overlays from hard links

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, icons

I have learned from [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251566.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and many other that the folder `winsxs` inside Windows folder contains a lot of hard linked folders. But none of the folders in `winsxs` shows shortcut overlays. However, when I create a hard link the folder shows a shortcut overlay, though the type is shown to be *File folder*. I want to create a hard link to my `workspace` folder in `E:` drive in my documents library, so that it is elegant and easy to navigate to. But the shortcut overlay bothers me. Below is a screenshot.

[image: hard linked file folder displaying shortcut overlay]

Is there any way to create hard links without showing the shortcut overlay?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not allow you to create hard links for directories. Also, only *files* are hard-linked under Winsxs, not directories, as far as I know. 
This means what you are creating is probably a directory symbolic link or a directory junction.

EDIT:

The [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) might help.

Comment: That's nice information, but it doesn't answer the question of how to remove the shortcut overlay. Once you have sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment everywhere. - [From Review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/507164)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: To be fair, the question is invalid - you can't hardlink directories in NTFS - and ey does point this out. It should have been a comment, but until the answer was upvoted, ey had no karma at all so commenting on questions wasn't possible.